# Two objects value is null; why?

Tags: java, localdate

Method parameter sd & ed is LocalDate, I need return date object, but sd & ed return null.
My define a private method:

```
private void setQuarter(LocalDate sd,LocalDate ed,LocalDate today){
            switch (getQuarter(today.getMonthValue())){
                case 1:
                    sd=LocalDate.of(today.getYear(),1,1);
                    ed=LocalDate.of(today.getYear(),3,31);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    sd=LocalDate.of(today.getYear(),4,1);
                    ed=LocalDate.of(today.getYear(),6,30);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    sd=LocalDate.of(today.getYear(),7,1);
                    ed=LocalDate.of(today.getYear(),9,30);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    sd=LocalDate.of(today.getYear(),10,1);
                    ed=LocalDate.of(today.getYear(),12,31);
                    break;
                default:
                    sd=LocalDate.of(today.getYear()+1,1,1);
                    ed=LocalDate.of(today.getYear()+1,1,1);
            }
        }
```

Invoke this method:

```
LocalDate sd=null;
LocalDate ed=null;

setQuarter(sd,ed,today);

log.info("==> sd:{},ed:{}",sd,ed);
```

Output message:
==> sd:null,ed:null

Comment: Are you initializing `today`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because in Java parameters of methods pass by value.
Reference(i.e. a pointer) pass by value of reference(address of the object).

The code should look like this:

```
Pair<LocalDate, LocalDate> dates = getSdAndEd(today);
LocalDate sd = dates.getLeft();
LocalDate ed = dates.getRight();

private Pair<LocalDate, LocalDate> getSdAndEd(LocalDate today){
    switch (getQuarter(today.getMonthValue())){
        case 1:
            return Pair.of(
                    LocalDate.of(today.getYear(),1,1),
                    LocalDate.of(today.getYear(),3,31)
            )
        case 2:
          ...
    }
}
```

In example `Pair`-class from *Apache Commons Lang* »  `group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.9'`.

Comment: Why is LocalDate is by value, if parameter is Map, it by value of reference?

Comment: LocalDate is the reference -> that right, in parameters of method was copying the value of reference

Comment: Thank you very much answers.